# vwnt pop up in smalltalk

Tags: smalltalk, visualworks, gnu-smalltalk

When I try to open my smalltalk project file vwnt pops up. The project wont open. I did save the project properly last time I was working on it. Please help if anyone know how to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 1):

what do you mean by smalltalk project files? VisualWorks doesn't have anything like that. What it has is an .im and .cha file. the .im file is the image, which contains VisualWorks and all the changes you did to it. So when you open the .im file, it'll open VisualWorks. You create classes and methods in VisualWorks and by doing so you modify the whole system. When you save the image, the whole VisualWorks system gets persisted and when you open the image file again, the system is restored. 
The .cha file is a text file that contains all the changes that you did to the image.